# Most recent revision; latest revision; or last revision?

Tags: adjectives, time

In official documents that are revised on a regular basis, which would be the correct/most natural phrase to use for the slot where you enter the date on which the document was last revised – "most recent revision", "latest revision", or "last revision"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Most recent revision: [date]" and "Latest revision: [date]" are both good.

"Last revision: [date]" is probably fine, too, but I prefer "Last revised: [date]", to avoid the possible implication (which may only be a result of overthinking) that the "last" revision is the final one.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose someone finds an out-dated version. If it says "latest" or "most recent" revision it isn't actually true. It's misleading, so I suggest the factual

> Revision date

without struggling to find an appropriate adjective.

Comment: But sometimes you want to actually express that something was last revised on a certain date - i.e., that there *is* no more recent version. Obviously in that case you have to be careful about not leaving around outdated versions. In any case, the OP gave three suggestions that all assume that this additional piece of information is included in the dating mechanism, and merely asked which is most natural. I don't see this answer as addressing that question.

Comment: @cruthers yes, but, outdated versions do get left around, as hard copy, on neglected websites, etc. When would a revision *not* be the "latest" revision? It's almost a tautology.

Comment: For example, in a previous job, my team would share a document among ourselves and maybe a client. The document would be periodically updated. It might be marked "latest revision: [date]" or "last updated: [date]" or the like, so we all knew how current the info on it was. If it said "[date] revision," that could be potentially confusing. Someone might think there might be another, separate and more recent version of the document, rather than that only one document is maintained and periodically updated and re-dated.

Comment: Well, as my answer says, I think that is wrong. It's the *date* that gives you the relevant information, and it is usually impossible to destroy earlier ones, or to go around changing them to: "previous version", "last but one version" etc. Finding an obsolete document that says "latest version" is even more confusing than looking at the actual date.

Comment: Impossible to destroy? You just resave the document with the new information on it.

Comment: Yes, documents always proliferate. But *if* there are no other versions of the document then it's pointless to say "latest version". The date says it all. Aside: I worked in a technology company where the documentation office would never release an electronic version of a document, because colleagues would edit it and redistribute it. You only ever got hard copy, dated.

Comment: If the date says it all, you don't even need "Revision Date," as you've suggested. The point is, your suggestion of "revision date" simply means something different from the three suggestions of the OP, which would be appropriate in the business scenario that I described, and which is far from uncommon, regardless of your hard-copy scenario, and which therefore should provide the basis for an answer to this question.

Comment: @cruthers putting "revision date" makes it clear that this wasn't the only version. If it was you who downvoted, that's bad form when you have posted an answer yourself. Even if it wasn't you, it is still bad form to argue that your answer is better. If I think the right answer to a question is "none of those" then that is what I will write.

Comment: Weather Vane and @cruthers Thank you for an interesting discussion! I have to say I agree more with you, Weather Vane, at the same time as cruthers is right that your answer doesn't quite answer my original question – for this reason I have now checked cruther's answer as the one solving my question, instead of yours. I'm not sure why you have no up votes though, because I've certainly up-voted your answer... Anyway. The situation you (Weather Vane) describe, with a number of different versions of the same document in circulation, is certainly all too common, at least in my experience...